# How to simplify jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have this jQuery selector:

```
'div.i_like.user0:not(.dsbl),div.i_like.zero:not(.dsbl)'
```

in

```
Picks.MainNode.on('mouseenter', 'div.i_like.user0:not(.dsbl),div.i_like.zero:not(.dsbl)', function(e) ...
```

Is there any way to group `.user0` and `.zero` to more simple selector?

Comment: No. But do you need this to be a selector ? Are your elements dynamically added ?

Comment: Unlikely.... only thing you can do is check whether you really need to use two classes to identify each element.

Comment: And if you don't need the initial "div", remove it. It doesn't make the things better.

Comment: I usually store it into a var and add to the on method.

Comment: Can you show markup as well, and tell us what is dynamic

Comment: I would go for the var, too.

Comment: @dystroy Why? I read that this speed-up selector in old browsers without `querySelector`

Comment: @Rustam in the context in which you're using the selector (a delegated event handler), the complexity will have almost no impact on performance.

Comment: @vittore No, question about simplifying this selector. I know ways how to simplify it without delegated event using `filter`

Comment: @Pointy Does this rule work for IE7 where there are no support for getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @Rustam in a delegated event handler, the check against the selector will only be done when the event happens, and then only against one target element. It will be slower in IE7, but still very fast in absolute terms.

Comment: @Ian it does not have to call `getElementsBy` anything because it's an event handler. There's only ever one element to check (well, one per level of element nesting, but still a relatively short list).  It's only effectively doing `.is()` tests, in other words, on elements that have already been "found" by the fact of the event taking place.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm, I guess I was just referring to normal event binding. Obviously, you're right, I'm just confusing myself with delegation (even though I know how it works). Every time it has to be parsed and then evaluated against the target element. That's definitely not too bad, but since having more leading selectors like "div" might help "short-circuit" the selector for non-matches.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for better understanding principles of delegated events. As I understand after `mouseenter` happened on Picks.MainNode, jQuery will find all parents from e.target until Picks.MainNode and compare them to selector? This also called event bubbling?

Comment: @Rustam yes exactly. It's good for selectors to be efficient, but in this case it's probably not the most critical thing for script performance.

Comment: @Pointy In fact I supposed it works like this but I spent 5 minutes trying to make sense of jQuery code on this point. Do you have a reference to confirm it ? The sizzle code isn't the most obvious one...

Comment: @dystroy well in the 1.7 code there's a function called "dispatch" where it seems to do the work, and it looks like it's written to be pretty efficient.